# How to hide particular JS warnings

Tags: css, angular, css-variables

[My previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48138238/custom-css-attributes-for-angular-components) deals with custom css properties producing a warning in the console.  Since no one seems to know the answer, is there a way to simply hide the warnings?

Comment: You should not be hiding any warnings since there are good reasons they appear...

Comment: simply correct them and they will be hidden

Comment: I know hiding warnings isn't ideal.  However, in lieu of an proper fix, it makes life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Use try-catch to handle exceptions

```js
try {
    //statements suspected to throw exception.
}
catch(e) {
}
```

To hide JavaScript errors from the user

```js
$(window).error(function(){
    return true;
});
```

or you can put the following script code in the  section of your page:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    <!--
    function silentErrorHandler() {return true;}
    window.onerror=silentErrorHandler;
    //-->
</script>
```

Comment: This solution is not really that helpful.  How should this be applied in my case?